# Auto increment just one cell only when condition meets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I auto increment one cell only (A1 for e.g)  if A2 meets the condition? Here is an example.

`If A2 = 2, A1+150` and keep that new value even if `A2` changes back. But once `A2 = 2` happens again, I want a newly added value `A1` to be added another `150` again. This time `A1= A1 + 150 + 150` after `A2=2` happens for 2nd time. 
Can be be done through just spreadsheet or need a google script? or is there a better idea to auto add the Cell A1.

Comment: create trigger on change, if previous A2 <> 2 and current A2 = 2 then A1=A1+100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more details on user11982798's comment: you can use the `onEdit()` trigger for this. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers.

This code will probably do what you need:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "A2" && e.oldValue != 2 && e.value == 2) e.range.getSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(e.range.getSheet().getRange("A1").getValue() + 150);
}
```

In case you want to refine further the conditions (e.g. only do so for a certain sheet, or for several cells,...) check the documentation of the `event` object here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

... and of course the overall Spreadsheet App Script documentation.

Comment: Thank you boss! It works just the way I want. I am assuming it cannot be done through just simple excel or spreadsheet.

Comment: None that I can think of, but I'd happily see such a solution if someone can think of one.